# Middleman blogging

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm using the awesome [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com) to create my blog.
Everything works fine when working in development server: not a single error, everything is clean.

When I run `bundle exec middleman build` though, I get a bunch of errors here and there.
They go like this:

```
    error  build/blog/2013/01/01.html
undefined method `title' for #<Middleman::Sitemap::Resource:0x10242aa60>

   error  build/tag.html
undefined local variable or method `tagname' for #<Middleman::Application::MiddlemanApplication1:0x102283040>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird, and sounds like either a bug or something we should make into a better error message. Could you file an issue at https://github.com/middleman/middleman-blog/issues and include your `config.rb` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to do that tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the middleman-blog gem to your Gemfile and run bundle update? Did you configure the blog in config.rb? Check the [official docs](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have configured the blog to use the tag template in your `config.rb` with something like `blog.tag_template = "tag.html"`. Although if you are not using this feature, you can just remove the `tag.html.erb` file from your source directory.